# Rate of convergence of sojourn times of Markov chains

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$ be a time-homogeneous Markov chain with finite state space $\Omega$.
Assume that $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$ is irreducible and aperiodic and let $\pi$ be its stationary distribution.
By the ergodic theorem for Markov chains, the sojourn time of any set $A\subset\Omega$, $s_{n}(A) = \frac1n ∑_{k = 0}^{n-1} χ_A(X_k)$, converges to $\pi(A)$ almost surely as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

What I am looking for is a bound on the probability $\mathbb P(|s_{n}(A) - \pi(A)| > \epsilon)$ that the sojourn time differs by more than $\epsilon$ from $\pi(A)$ as a function of $n$ for given $\epsilon > 0$.
I can obtain such a bound, but I expect that there are results on this and would prefer to cite those.
Can anyone supply to suitable reference? Thanks!